# Mod_Rewrite Exclude a url (URI Exception)

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am using this mod-rewrite rule to redirect the just the homepage of my site to the /it/ sub-directory on the same site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://www.example.com/it/
```

However, I want to exempt this url from being redirected

```
http://www.example.com/?act=25
```

How can I write an exempt condition to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^act=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/it/
```

Oh, and RewriteCond does not work with RedirectMatch in case you didn't know (I didn't and wasted hrs because of it)